# Fourier transfrom of $te^{-2t}$ for $t\geq 0$

Tags: calculus, fourier-analysis

I'm trying to calculate the fourier transform of Fourier transfrom of $te^{-2t}$ for $t\geq0$.

I'm given the hint that the fourier transform of a function that has the form $e^{-at}f(t)$ is $F(a + iw)$. So if I let $f(t)=t$, I first need to calculate:

$$F(w) = \int_0^{\infty}te^{-iwt}$$

Now I have some problems calculating that integral, I'm using integration by parts with $u = t, v' = e^{-iwt}$:

$$F(w) = \int_0^{\infty}te^{-iwt} = \frac{it}{w}e^{-iwt} |_0 ^{\infty} - \frac{i}{w}\int_0^{\infty}e^{-iwt} = \frac{it}{w}e^{-iwt} |_0 ^{\infty} + \frac{1}{w^2}e^{-iwt}$$

And I don't know how to evaluate the limit of $\frac{it}{w}e^{-iwt}$ as $t \rightarrow \infty$.

Can anybody help me with that and tell me whether this has been correct up until this point?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Fourier transform should be:
$$
F(w) = \int_0^{\infty}te^{-2t}e^{-iwt}dt = \int_0^{\infty}te^{-(2+iw)t}dt
$$
Then using integration by parts with $u = t$ and $dv = e^{-(2+iw)t}dt$ you find:
$$
F(w) = \left.-\frac{t}{2+iw}e^{-(2+iw)t}\right\vert_0^{\infty} + \frac{1}{2+iw}\int_0^{\infty}e^{-(2+iw)t}dt = \frac{1}{2+iw}\int_0^{\infty}e^{-(2+iw)t}dt
$$
since $\mbox{lim}_{t\rightarrow \infty}\left(-\frac{t}{2+iw}e^{-(2+iw)t}\right) = 0$ (as can be checked using l'Hopital's rule, for example). But now of course, the final integral above yields simply:
$$
F(w) = \left.-\frac{e^{-(2+iw)t}}{(2+iw)^2}\right\vert_0^{\infty} = \frac{1}{(2+iw)^2}
$$

This of course has the form $G(a + iw)$ where $a = 2$ and $G(x) = \frac{1}{x^2}$ but I worry that perhaps in trying to apply this hint, you got confused. As you can see, it's quite straightforward to just determine the Fourier transform the old-fashioned way in this case.